# Trying to install MS Office with wine via winetricks

Tags: 13.04, winetricks

Installed Wine from the software centre for Ubuntu 13.04, but I cannot see Winetricks in the dash despite Synaptic telling me it is installed.

I have tried just using Wine but it fails half way through insallation with no useful message.

I previously installed successfully this way in 12.04

Answer (score 1):

run `winetricks` in a terminal.

This should open it up, if it is installed.

Comment: Thanks BiggJJ. I found winetricks --GUI worked OK from terminal.